# AppImage .desktop file not showing on dock

Tags: gnome, 22.04, dash-to-dock

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.
I have two `.desktop` executable files for the [Keet](https://keet.io/downloads/1.2.1/Keet-x64.tar.gz) AppImage in my `.local/share/applications` folder, with the AppImage located in `/home/giovanni/snap` as listed in the Desktop Entry under `Exec` property.
I didn´t create them they have been created by the app I suppose.
However they are both not showing on my dock (I have [Dash to Dock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/) installed).
All the others AppImages are showing.
If I run them form the terminal with `gtk-launch keet` or `gtk-launch appimagekit_8d9752879526b100ab8504901c9bd0a4-Keet` the app starts succesfully.
Removing one of the two files and restarting the system does not fix the issue.
I'm not sure this is related, but I have AppImageLauncher installed and the AppImage is in the folder listed in his settings.
What can be the reason and how can I solve the issue?
The content of the files is:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Keet
Exec=/home/giovanni/snap/Keet_7695b52a4e54b87f751f760f6ab65255.AppImage %U
Terminal=false
Icon=keet
Type=Application
StartupWMClass=Keet
X-AppImage-Version=1.0.1
Comment=Keet
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/punch;x-scheme-handler/holepunch
```

and :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Keet
Exec=/home/giovanni/snap/Keet_7695b52a4e54b87f751f760f6ab65255.AppImage
Icon=appimagekit_8d9752879526b100ab8504901c9bd0a4_keet
Type=Application
Categories=Network;AudioVideo;

TryExec=/home/giovanni/snap/Keet_7695b52a4e54b87f751f760f6ab65255.AppImage
X-AppImage-Old-Icon=keet
X-AppImage-Identifier=8d9752879526b100ab8504901c9bd0a4
Actions=Remove;
X-AppImageLauncher-Version=2.2.0 (git commit 0f91801), built on 2020-09-29 21:36:15 UTC
```

Comment: 1) Which file is which? 2) Where is the Keet appimage located? The way you write it, it is located in `.local/share/applications`, but that is probably more where your .desktop launcher is located. Edit your question and make it more accurate and precise.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend installing [AppImageLauncher](https://github.com/TheAssassin/AppImageLauncher/releases). It integrates AppImages with the desktop and deals with the desktop files for you. After you install AppImageLauncher, the first time you run an AppImage, it will ask if you want to integrated it, or just run the AppImage. If you choose to integrate, it will move the `.appimage` file to a known location you can set like `~/Applications` and ensure the application shows up on the desktop menu/launcher. It's very easy to use, and makes the whole process of using AppImages much smoother.

Once you launch an AppImage, you can then right click it and "pin" it to your launcher.

Comment: I forgot to mention that AppImageLauncher is already installed and this AppImage is already in the folder listed in AppImageLauncher settings. I'm editing the question now.